# Creating First Person Controls in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, frame-rate

I'm trying to make first person movement controls for a simple FPS. I'd like to make in flash, but I'm struggling with directional movement.

*Summary:*  I'd like to be able to create FPS controls in flash, but can't seem to get it right.

*Details:*
I'm using a method by which rotations are applied to a movieclip (`mc`) that remains stationary with its pivot point underneath your point of view, so that the world seemingly rotates around you when the mouse is moved.

I then apply directional movements to a moveclip (`box`) nested within the rotating movieclip (`mc`) to give the illusion of walking around in a first person view.

`mc` - Handles rotation *(a container for `box`)*

-----`box` - Handles translation *(`box` serves as the floor, so I have it as a black square)*

The problem begins when you rotate `mc` and begin moving with the arrow keys.  `box`'s translation doesn't take `mc`'s rotation in consideration, and so you're still locked to the x and y axis of `box` so, no matter where you face, you're always locked onto those axis as opposed to the traditional move forward wherever you're facing that most FPS games employ.

I haven't a clue of where to go from here, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Timeline code:

```
//You’ll need a symbol named mc. With another symbol named box within it.
//mc should be centered on the stage.
//stage size 1920x1080


var mL: Boolean = false;
var mR: Boolean = false;
var mD: Boolean = false;
var mU: Boolean = false;

var speed: int = 10;

mc.rotationX=90;
mc.y=1000;

mc.x=932.1;
mc.z=0;
mc.width=980;
mc.height=98;



stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, EF);

function EF(e: Event): void {
//Rotates mc based on distance of mouseX to the center of the stage.
    if(mouseX<stage.stageWidth){
        mc.rotationY += speed*((mouseX-stage.stageWidth/2)*.0001);
    }
    if(mouseX>stage.stageWidth){
        mc.rotationY += speed*((mouseX-stage.stageWidth/2)*.0001);
    }


//Arrow key controls.
    if (mL == true) {
        mc.box.x += speed;
    }
    if (mR == true) {
        mc.box.x -= speed;
    }
    if (mD == true) {
        mc.box.y += speed;
    }
    if (mU == true) {
        mc.box.y -= speed;
    }

}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, kD);
function kD(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
//Key down conditionals.
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && mR == false && mD == false && mU == false) {
        mL = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && mR == false && mD == false && mU == true) {
        mL = true;
        mU = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && mR == false && mD == false && mL == true) {
        mL = true;
        mU = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT && mR == false && mD == true && mU == false) {
        mL = true;
        mD = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && mR == false && mU == false && mL == true) {
        mL = true;
        mD = true;
    }


    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && mL == false && mD == false && mU == false) {
        mR = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && mL == false && mD == false && mU == true) {
        mR = true;
        mU = true;
    }
     if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && mL == false && mD == false && mR == true) {
        mR = true;
        mU = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT && mL == false && mD == true && mU == false) {
        mR = true;
        mD = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && mL == false && mU == false && mR == true) {
        mR = true;
        mD = true;
    }


    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP && mR == false && mD == false && mL == false) {
        mU = true;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN && mL == false && mR == false && mU == false) {
        mD = true;
    }


}

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, kU);
function kU(e: KeyboardEvent): void {
//Key up conditionals.
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT) {
        mL = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT) {
        mR = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP) {
        mU = false;
    }
    if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN) {
        mD = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make one key press (forward) add relative amounts of x and y positioning.  You'll need a little trigonometry here.  You are going to use the `mc.rotationY` as the angle.

```
if (mU == true) {
    mc.box._speed += speed; // instead of mc.box.y -= speed;
    mc.box._ySpeed = Math.sin(mc.rotationY)*mc.box._speed;
    mc.box._xSpeed = Math.cos(mc.rotationY)*mc.box._speed;
}
```

similarly update your other logical statements.

And then add a final function to update locations:

```
mc.box.y += mc.box._ySpeed;
mc.box.x += mc.box._xSpeed;
```

This is the basic idea.  You might have to do some conversions between radians and degrees, but there are plenty of resources to help you with that, and I always get it wrong without being able to test, which I can't do right now.